# How to implement subcription in Android SDK

Tags: android, payment-gateway

In the app can we add a yearly subscription method, so that it stop working each year if subscription is off Or the current year payment won't went successful.

Any Ideas would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A search on SO revealed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410550/in-android-market-is-there-a-subscription-facility
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575614/android-subscription-based-licensing
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225342/android-app-subscription
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793451/android-subscription-and-payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [In-App Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html)

Alternatively, if you allow your customers to create an account on your web site. They could pay you there and you could use your own servers to verify the subscription by calling it from the app.

Comment: But I am still trying to go for PayPal. If you have some help then plz do so.